# Error when you change the order of columns in Dbgrid

Tags: delphi, drag-and-drop, delphi-7, delphi-xe2, dbgrid

I wrote the code for the form rendering settings database table Dbgrid in another form. It depends on the selected items are defined Chetsklistboks visible columns in Dbgrid. I also wrote the code to move with drag & drop items and columns Chetsklistbox Dbgrid conformity. But start at some point (and in my opinion with an attempt to change the item with the lowest index in the item with a large index) errors when drag & drop from the Argument out of range and when you close the Invalid Pointer Operation. Help resolve the error.

```
unit SettingOfShowData;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.CheckLst, Vcl.ExtCtrls,
  VirtualTrees, DatabaseClasses, MainForm, ListOfTables;

type
  TNodeField=record
    NameField : string;
end;

 PNodeField=^TNodeField;
type
  TfmSettings = class(TForm)
    Panel1: TPanel;
    VT: TVirtualStringTree;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Edit3: TEdit;
    CheckListBox1: TCheckListBox;
    procedure VTGetNodeDataSize(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
      var NodeDataSize: Integer);
    procedure VTGetText(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; Node: PVirtualNode;
      Column: TColumnIndex; TextType: TVSTTextType; var CellText: string);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure VTFreeNode(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; Node: PVirtualNode);
    procedure FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
    function IsPrimaryKey(InputTableName : string; InputFieldName : string) : Boolean;
    procedure VTNodeClick(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; const HitInfo: THitInfo);
    procedure VTNodeDblClick(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; const HitInfo: THitInfo);
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
    procedure CheckListBox1ClickCheck(Sender: TObject);
    procedure CheckListBox1DragDrop(Sender, Source: TObject; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure CheckListBox1DragOver(Sender, Source: TObject; X, Y: Integer;
      State: TDragState; var Accept: Boolean);
    procedure CheckListBox1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  fmSettings: TfmSettings;
  NumX, NumY : Integer;
implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TfmSettings.CheckListBox1ClickCheck(Sender: TObject);
begin
    fmShowData.DBGrid1.Columns[CheckListBox1.ItemIndex].Visible :=
    not(fmShowData.DBGrid1.Columns[CheckListBox1.ItemIndex].Visible);
end;

procedure TfmSettings.CheckListBox1DragDrop(Sender, Source: TObject; X,
  Y: Integer);
var
  Num1, Num2, temp: Integer;
  Point1, Point2: TPoint;
begin
  Point1.X:=NumX;
  Point1.Y:=NumY;
  Point2.X:=X;
  Point2.Y:=Y;
  with Source as TCheckListBox do
  begin
    Num2:=CheckListBox1.ItemAtPos(Point1,True);
    Num1:=CheckListBox1.ItemAtPos(Point2,True);
    CheckListBox1.Items.Move(Num2, Num1);
    if Num2>Num1 then
        begin
           temp:=Num2;
           Num2:=Num1;
           Num1:=temp;
        end;
    fmShowData.DBGrid1.Columns[Num1].Index:=Num2;
    fmShowData.DBGrid1.Columns[Num2+1].Index:=Num1;
  end;
end;

procedure TfmSettings.CheckListBox1DragOver(Sender, Source: TObject; X,
  Y: Integer; State: TDragState; var Accept: Boolean);
begin
  if Source=CheckListBox1 then Accept:=True;
end;

procedure TfmSettings.CheckListBox1MouseDown(Sender: TObject;
  Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  NumY:=Y;
  NumX:=X;
end;

procedure TfmSettings.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Index, i: Integer;
  VTNodeField : PNodeField;
begin
  VT.BeginUpdate();
  //TableSpec:=TTableSpec(DBSchema.Tables.FindComponent(fmListOfTables.DisplayTable));
  for Index := 0 to TTableSpec(DBSchema.Tables.FindComponent(fmListOfTables.DisplayTable)).Fields.ComponentCount-1 do
  begin
    if TTableSpec(DBSchema.Tables.FindComponent(fmListOfTables.DisplayTable)).Fields.Components[Index] is TFieldSpec then
    begin
      VTNodeField:=VT.GetNodeData(VT.AddChild(nil, nil));
      VTNodeField^.NameField:=(TTableSpec(DBSchema.Tables.FindComponent(fmListOfTables.DisplayTable)).Fields.Components[Index] as TFieldSpec).name;
    end;
  end;
  VT.EndUpdate();
for i := 0 to TTableSpec(DBSchema.Tables.FindComponent(fmListOfTables.DisplayTable)).Fields.ComponentCount-1 do
begin
  if (TTableSpec(DBSchema.Tables.FindComponent(fmListOfTables.DisplayTable)).Fields.Components[i] is TFieldSpec) then
    begin
      CheckListBox1.Items.Add(TTableSpec(DBSchema.Tables.FindComponent(fmListOfTables.DisplayTable)).Fields.Components[i].Name);
      CheckListBox1.Checked[i]:=true;
    end;
end;
end;

procedure TfmSettings.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
var i: integer;
begin
 { while VT.ComponentCount>0 do
  begin
    VT.DeleteNode(VT.Nodes.GetEnumerator.Current);
    VT.DeleteChildren(VT.Nodes.GetEnumerator.Current);
    VT.Nodes.GetEnumerator.MoveNext();
  end; }
  VT.Clear();
  //fmTableData.DBGrid1.Columns
  CheckListBox1.Clear;
end;

procedure TfmSettings.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Index: Integer;
  VTNodeField : PNodeField;
  //TableSpec : TTableSpec;
begin
 { VT.BeginUpdate();
  //TableSpec:=TTableSpec(DBSchema.Tables.FindComponent(fmListOfTables.DisplayTable));
  for Index := 0 to TTableSpec(DBSchema.Tables.FindComponent(fmListOfTables.DisplayTable)).ComponentCount-1 do
  begin
    if TTableSpec(DBSchema.Tables.FindComponent(fmListOfTables.DisplayTable)).Components[Index] is TFieldSpec then
    begin
      VTNodeField:=VT.GetNodeData(VT.AddChild(nil, nil));
      VTNodeField.NameField:=(TTableSpec(DBSchema.Tables.FindComponent(fmListOfTables.DisplayTable)).Components[Index] as TFieldSpec).FieldName;
    end;
  end;
  VT.EndUpdate();}
end;

procedure TfmSettings.VTFreeNode(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; Node: PVirtualNode);
var
  Data: PNodeField;
begin
  Data:=Sender.GetNodeData(Node);
  if Assigned(Data) then
  begin
    Finalize(Data^);
  end;
end;

procedure TfmSettings.VTGetNodeDataSize(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  var NodeDataSize: Integer);
begin
  NodeDataSize:=SizeOf(TNodeField);
end;

procedure TfmSettings.VTGetText(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; Node: PVirtualNode;
  Column: TColumnIndex; TextType: TVSTTextType; var CellText: string);
var
  Index: Integer;
  VTNodeField : PNodeField;
begin
  VTNodeField:=Sender.GetNodeData(Node);
  for Index := 0 to DBSchema.Tables.FindComponent(fmListOfTables.DisplayTable).ComponentCount-1 do
  begin
    if DBSchema.Tables.FindComponent(fmListOfTables.DisplayTable).Components[Index] is TFieldSpec then
    begin
      VTNodeField:=Sender.GetNodeData(Sender.AddChild(nil, nil));
      VTNodeField^.NameField:=(DBSchema.Tables.FindComponent(fmListOfTables.DisplayTable).Components[Index] as TFieldSpec).name;
    end;
  end;
  CellText:=VTNodeField^.NameField;
end;

procedure TfmSettings.VTNodeClick(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  const HitInfo: THitInfo);
var
  NewVTNodeField : PNodeField;
  NewNode : PVirtualNode;
begin
  {NewNode:=VT.AddChild(VT.FocusedNode);
  NewVTNodeField:=VT.GetNodeData(NewNode); }
end;

procedure TfmSettings.VTNodeDblClick(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  const HitInfo: THitInfo);
var
  NewVTNodeField, CurrentNode: PNodeField;
  NewNode : PVirtualNode;
  //CurrentNode : PDataNode;
  i, j : integer;
begin
 { NewNode:=VT.AddChild(VT.FocusedNode);
  NewVTNodeField:=VT.GetNodeData(NewNode); }
  CurrentNode:=VT.GetNodeData(VT.FocusedNode);
  if IsPrimaryKey(fmListOfTables.DisplayTable, {VT.Text[VT.FocusedNode, 0]} CurrentNode^.NameField) then
    begin
    for i:= 0 to DBSchema.Tables.ComponentCount-1 do
      for j:=0 to TTableSpec(DBSchema.Tables.Components[i]).Constraints.ComponentCount-1 do
      begin
         if (TConstraintSpec(TTableSpec(DBSchema.Tables.Components[i]).Constraints.Components[j]).Reference=fmListOfTables.DisplayTable) then
         begin
             NewNode:=VT.AddChild(VT.FocusedNode);
             NewVTNodeField:=VT.GetNodeData(NewNode);
             NewVTNodeField^.NameField:=(TTableSpec(DBSchema.Tables.Components[i])).Name;
         end;
      end;
    end;
end;

function TfmSettings.IsPrimaryKey(InputTableName : string; InputFieldName: string):Boolean;
var
  i : integer;
  flag: boolean;
begin
  flag:=False;
  for i:=0 to TTableSpec(DBSchema.Tables.FindComponent(InputTableName)).Constraints.ComponentCount-1 do
    begin
      if ((TConstraintSpec(TTableSpec(DBSchema.Tables.FindComponent(InputTableName)).Constraints.Components[i]).ConstraintType='PRIMARY') and (TFieldSpec(TConstraintDetailSpec(TConstraintSpec(TTableSpec(DBSchema.Tables.FindComponent(InputTableName)).Constraints.Components[i]).DetailList).FieldSpec).FieldName=InputFieldName){(TTableSpec(DBSchema.Tables.FindComponent(InputTableName)).Fields.FindComponent(InputFieldName).Name=TConstraintDetailSpec(TConstraintSpec(TTableSpec(DBSchema.Tables.FindComponent(InputTableName)).Constraints.Components[i]).DetailList).FieldName)}) then
        flag:=True;
      Edit1.Text:=TConstraintSpec(TTableSpec(DBSchema.Tables.FindComponent(InputTableName)).Constraints.Components[i]).Name;
      Edit2.Text:=AnsiToUtf8(TFieldSpec(TConstraintDetailSpec(TConstraintSpec(TTableSpec(DBSchema.Tables.FindComponent(InputTableName)).Constraints.Components[i]).DetailList).FieldSpec).FieldName);
      Edit3.Text:=InputFieldName;
    end;
  Result:=flag;
end;
end.
```

Select the code of procedure that changes the order of the columns

```
procedure TfmSettings.CheckListBox1DragDrop(Sender, Source: TObject; X,
  Y: Integer);
var
  Num1, Num2, temp: Integer;
  Point1, Point2: TPoint;
begin
  Point1.X:=NumX;
  Point1.Y:=NumY;
  Point2.X:=X;
  Point2.Y:=Y;
  with Source as TCheckListBox do
  begin
    Num2:=CheckListBox1.ItemAtPos(Point1,True);
    Num1:=CheckListBox1.ItemAtPos(Point2,True);
    CheckListBox1.Items.Move(Num2, Num1);
    if Num2>Num1 then
        begin
           temp:=Num2;
           Num2:=Num1;
           Num1:=temp;
        end;
    fmShowData.DBGrid1.Columns[Num1].Index:=Num2;
    fmShowData.DBGrid1.Columns[Num2+1].Index:=Num1;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Do you know how to use the Delphi debugger?

Answer (score 0):

If then checklistbox is a representation of the fields the corresponding Action for

```
CheckListBox1.Items.Move(Num2, Num1);
```

would be

```
DBGrid1.Columns[num2].Index := DBGrid1.Columns[num1].Index;
```

nothing more or less.

// Removed comment thx to  jachguate

Comment: the declared Num1, Num2 <> NumX, NumY, which maybe are global variables or class members visible within the scope of the method, not  _random stackdata_ involved in that assignment.